# Google script find specific text in a row range then skip current iteration of a loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to find the keywords "Listing Agent" in each row between columns E through N. If it appears, increment to next row++ then skip the current loop and try the next row. But it just copies the row anyways.

Here is the whole function.

```
function copydata() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data Entry");
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  var v
  var row = 6

  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("B"+(last_row+1)+":W"+(last_row+1));

  for (var i = 0; i< 27; i++){
    v = source_sheet.getRange("E" + row + ":N" + row).getValues();
    if (v[i] == "Listing Agent"){  
      row++
      continue;
    }
    var triggerCell = source_sheet.getRange("AB" + row).getValue();      
    if (triggerCell  ==  0){
      var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("B" + row + ":W" + row);        
      target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
      source_range.copyTo(target_range, {contentsOnly:true});        
    }
    row++
  }

  ss.setActiveSheet(source_sheet);
  source_sheet.getRange('C2').clearContent();
  ss.setActiveSelection("C2");

  Browser.msgBox("Your data has been moved.");
  //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Data has been moved.", "Data Copied");  
 }
```

I am sure it has to do with this part.

```
  for (var i = 0; i< 27; i++){
    v = source_sheet.getRange("E" + row + ":N" + row).getValues();
    if (v[i] == "Listing Agent"){  
      row++
      continue;
    }
```

I have tried several different ways, none of them are working like I intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values retrieved by `getValues()` is an 2 dimensional array. And in order to know whether a value is included in an array, you can use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). The modified script is as follows.

#### From :

```
if (v[i] == "Listing Agent"){
  row++
  continue;
}
```

#### To :

```
if (~v[0].indexOf("Listing Agent")){
  row++
  continue;
}
```

The detail information of `getValues()` is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()).

#### Note :

When I saw the modified script, I thought that the time to run the script might be a bit long. So I modified the "for loop". At first, all data is retrieved, and using retrieved data, the data is processed. But I don't know whether this works fine. So if this didn't work, I'm sorry.

```
function copydata() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data Entry");
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();

  var ar = [];
  var data = source_sheet.getRange("B6:AB32").getValues(); // Here, all data is retrieved. The rows are obtained from "var row = 6" and "for (var i = 0; i< 27; i++){".
  data.forEach(function(e){
    if (!~e.indexOf("Listing Agent")) {
      var temp = [];
      if (e[e.length - 1] == 0) {
        temp = e.slice(0, 22); // Here, data of "B" + row + ":W" + row is retrieved.
        ar.push(temp);
      }
    }
  });
  target_sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 1, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);

  ss.setActiveSheet(source_sheet);
  source_sheet.getRange('C2').clearContent();
  ss.setActiveSelection("C2");
  Browser.msgBox("Your data has been moved.");
}
```

If my understanding was wrong, I'm sorry.

Comment: Pretty good. My data is only in b6 to w32. The trigger cell is a duplicate data check for that row in data sheet. If it is a 0 copy that row b to w to data. If it is not 0, it is a duplicate.

Comment: I am attempting to use this now. Had to make 1 change.
`target_sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 1, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar); `

This way it pastes data starting at columb B right?
`target_sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 2, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar); `

Comment: @Arlen Gregory Yes. You can import the data using ``target_sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 2, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);``. I'm sorry my answer couldn't be useful for you.

Comment: Works perfectly and fast. Thank you for looking at this.

`target_sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 2, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);`

Does indeed paste the results into column B of destination like i needed it to do.

Comment: @Arlen Gregory I'm relieved to hear that.